# How to look for a registry key? 32/64 bit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, registry, visual-studio-2013, 32bit-64bit

How to look for a registry key? I need to look from both 32 and 64 bit systems with 3 diffrent GUID's.  I need to return the one it found the InstallLocation in to a TextBox. I have made the following code. Tho i don't know if it's actually usable. I am a beginner at this. Please help.

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Net
Imports System

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Is64Bit As Boolean

        Is64Bit = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"))

        If Not Is64Bit Then
            Try
                Dim rk32_1 As RegistryKey
                rk32_1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1EAC1D02-C6AC-4FA6-9A44-96258C37C812EU}_is1")
                Dim il_rk32_1 As String = rk32_1.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            Try
                Dim rk32_2 As RegistryKey
                rk32_2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1EAC1D02-C6AC-4FA6-9A44-96258C37C812NA}_is1")
                Dim il_rk32_2 As String = rk32_2.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            Try
                Dim rk32_3 As RegistryKey
                rk32_3 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1EAC1D02-C6AC-4FA6-9A44-96258C37C812RU}_is1")
                Dim il_rk32_3 As String = rk32_3.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If

        If Is64Bit Then
            Try
                Dim rk64_1 As RegistryKey
                rk64_1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1EAC1D02-C6AC-4FA6-9A44-96258C37C812EU}_is1")
                Dim il_rk64_1 As String = rk64_1.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            Try
                Dim rk64_2 As RegistryKey
                rk64_2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1EAC1D02-C6AC-4FA6-9A44-96258C37C812NA}_is1")
                Dim il_rk64_2 As String = rk64_2.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            Try
                Dim rk64_3 As RegistryKey
                rk64_3 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1EAC1D02-C6AC-4FA6-9A44-96258C37C812RU}_is1")
                Dim il_rk64_3 As String = rk64_3.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, keep in mind that if the program is compiled as x86, the `(IntPtr.Size * 8)` will always return `32` (if this is an issue, I do have a class that can get the OS version regardless of how the exe is compiled)

I'd recommend using the following :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Check if the OS is 64 bit
    Dim Is64Bit As Boolean = ((IntPtr.Size * 8) = 64)

    Dim UninstallPath As String = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

    If Is64Bit Then
        UninstallPath = UninstallPath.Insert(8, "\Wow6432Node")
    End If

    Dim il_rk32_1 As String = Nothing
    Dim il_rk32_2 As String = Nothing
    Dim il_rk32_3 As String = Nothing

    Try
        Dim rk32_1 As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(UninstallPath & "{1EAC1D02-C6AC-4FA6-9A44-96258C37C812EU}_is1")

        If rk32_1 IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim Val As Object = rk32_1.GetValue("InstallLocation")

            If Val IsNot Nothing Then
                il_rk32_1 = Val.ToString
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(il_rk32_1) Then
        il_rk32_1 = "C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\"
    End If

    Me.TextBox1.Text = il_rk32_1


    Try
        Dim rk32_2 As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(UninstallPath & "{1EAC1D02-C6AC-4FA6-9A44-96258C37C812NA}_is1")

        If rk32_2 IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim Val As Object = rk32_2.GetValue("InstallLocation")

            If Val IsNot Nothing Then
                il_rk32_2 = Val.ToString
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(il_rk32_2) Then
        il_rk32_2 = "C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\"
    End If

    Me.TextBox2.Text = il_rk32_2


    Try
        Dim rk32_3 As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(UninstallPath & "{1EAC1D02-C6AC-4FA6-9A44-96258C37C812RU}_is1")

        If rk32_3 IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim Val As Object = rk32_3.GetValue("InstallLocation")

            If Val IsNot Nothing Then
                il_rk32_3 = Val.ToString
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(il_rk32_3) Then
        il_rk32_3 = "C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\"
    End If

    Me.TextBox3.Text = il_rk32_3

End Sub
```

Edit:

I've changed the above code to accomedate the OP's question (in the comments)

Comment: I compile all EXE's with: "Any CPU"

Comment: @jyrka2 That's good, however there may come a time where it needs to be compiled as `x86` (COM related), so it's best to keep this in mind.

Comment: Sry, wrote wrong. I dont mean set value in registry to "C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\" ,but so it put that in the TextBox if no InstallLocation was found from registry.

Comment: **NEVER** access Wow6432Node key directly

Answer (score 1):

I didn't looked too much at your code 'cause you did the opposite checks. Wow64 refers to 32-Bit applications on 64-Bit machine.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) :

> WoW64 (Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit)
>
> The WoW64 subsystem also handles other key aspects of running 32-bit
>   applications. It is involved in managing the interaction of 32-bit
>   applications with the Windows components such as the Registry, which
>   has distinct keys for 64-bit and 32-bit applications. For example
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node is the 32-bit equivalent of
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software (although 32-bit applications are not
>   aware of this redirection). Some Registry keys are mapped from 64-bit
>   to their 32-bit equivalents, while others have their contents
>   mirrored, depending on the edition of Windows.

PS: Just to notice it, the same thing happens for `System32` and `SysWOW64` windows directories.

> UPDATE:

Just an easy way to retrieve whether the OS is x64 (instead of getting a Environment variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432` which could be faked in a x86 OS):

```
' Get OS Architecture
' ( By Elektro)
'
' Usage Examples :
' Dim OSArchitecture As Architecture = GetOSArchitecture()
' MsgBox(OSArchitecture.ToString)
'
''' <summary>
''' Determines whether the OS is 32 or 64 Bits.
''' </summary>
''' <returns>
''' The return value could be: 
''' '32' for 32-Bit OS (x86)
''' '64' for 64-Bit OS (x64)
''' </returns>
Private Function GetOSArchitecture() As Architecture

    Return [Enum].Parse(GetType(Architecture),
                        Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(IntPtr)) * 8)

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Indicates the possible processor architectures.
''' </summary>
Private Enum Architecture As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' 32-Bit
    ''' </summary>
    x86 = 32

    ''' <summary>
    ''' 64-Bit
    ''' </summary>
    x64 = 64

End Enum
```

Comment: So something like this?:                                                            `If GetOSArchitecture() = ("32") Then`
     
        `End If`
        `If GetOSArchitecture() = ("64") Then`

        `End If`

Comment: Nope, it's not an String type, ir returns an integer. I've elaborated more the code, an example of this could be: `Dim OSArchitecture As Architecture = GetOSArchitecture() : If OSArchitecture  = Architecture.x86 then : ElseIf OSArchitecture = Architecture.x64 Then : end if`

Answer (score 0):

In order to access application configuration installed from a .reg file, I had to write the following function:

```
Public Const RegRoot As String = "Software\MyApp\"

Function ReadFromRegister(ByRef FieldToRead As String) As String
    ReadFromRegister = ""
    Dim MyReg As RegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
    If MyReg Is Nothing Then
        End
    End If

    Dim MySubReg As RegistryKey = MyReg.OpenSubKey(RegRoot)
    If MySubReg Is Nothing Then
        End
    End If

    ReadFromRegister = MySubReg.GetValue(FieldToRead)
    MySubReg.Close()
    MyReg.Close()

End Function
```

Note that the function `OpenBaseKey` is introduced from **Framework 4** on.